# Convert rows to column for every nth row by ID

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I'm trying to convert rows to columns.

I have the following columns: `user_id, meta_key, meta_value`

I have the following rows: `'first_name', 'last_name', 'stillingsbetegnelse'`

Right now I can generate the rows and columns sorted and from a specific `user_id`. In my case it's from 15. This is with the following query :

```
SELECT user_id, meta_key, meta_value 
FROM DATA_A ORDER BY user_id DESC; 
where meta_key IN ('first_name', 'last_name', 'stillingsbetegnelse') 
AND user_id > 15;
```

And the result is:

```
user_id     meta_key                meta_value
16          first_name              Laxgdfds
16          last_name               Narentdsaa
16          stillingsbetegnelse     Andet
18          first_name              Riedsa
18          last_name               Joe
18          stillingsbetegnelse     Andet
```

(all information is anonymized)

How do I get the following output?

```
first_name    last_name         stillingsbetegnelse
Laxgdfds      Narentdsaa        Andet
Riedsa        Joe               Andet
```

I have tried methods with pivot, but I'm getting an error:

```
    select
        p.*
    from DATA_A
    pivot(
        max([meta_value])
        for [meta_key] in ([first_name], [last_name], [stillingsbetegnelse])
) as p
```

I think the problem is that I want to take values only from a certain ID. How can I implement this feature? I only want the states data above, but I'm getting a lot of other data, that I don't have any use for.
...........................

With help i found a solution from Stackoverflow. 
The solution is

```
> SELECT user_id,    MAX(IF(meta_key = 'first_name', meta_value,NULL))
> AS Fornavn,    MAX(IF(meta_key = 'last_name', meta_value,NULL)) AS
> Efternavn,    MAX(IF(meta_key = 'stillingsbetegnelse',
> meta_value,NULL)) AS  FROM DATA_A GROUP BY user_id;
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Feel free to add some DML to your post so users can easily start testing on your data

Comment: 1) Does the list of `meta_key` values is static? 2) Do NOT use the asterisk in pivot query. 3) Use `FROM (SELECT * FROM DATA_A) src` - it seems this table contains excess fields. See [FROM - Using PIVOT and UNPIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15), especially the examples.

Comment: Query works on my machine. With your input, it gives you the output you're asking for. Tested on MSSQL2016

Comment: You can add a simple where clause. WHERE UserId = x or User_id IN (x,y).

Comment: Found the solution with help from stackoverflow :)

Comment: If you found a solution you should probably post it as an answer, not part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code I ran to simulate the problem you had and see what the error message was and what to do, however when I ran it - it ran successfully.

```
CREATE TABLE #TestTable
(   [user_id]   varchar(50) NULL
,   [meta_key]  varchar(50) NULL
,   [meta_value]    VARCHAR(50) NULL
)

INSERT INTO #TestTable
VALUES  ('16'   , 'first_name'          , 'Laxgdfds'    )
    ,   ('16'   , 'last_name'           , 'Narentdsaa'  )
    ,   ('16'   , 'stillingsbetegnelse' , 'Andet'       )
    ,   ('18'   , 'first_name'          , 'Riedsa'      )
    ,   ('18'   , 'last_name'           , 'Joe'         )
    ,   ('18'   , 'stillingsbetegnelse' , 'Andet'       )

SELECT  P.*
FROM    #TestTable
PIVOT   (MAX([META_VALUE])
         FOR [META_KEY] IN ([FIRST_NAME], [LAST_NAME], [STILLINGSBETEGNELSE])
        ) AS P
```

So I would recommend 1) copying and running my code, and if that doesn't work responding back with the error message. 2) If my code works with no error message, then I would recommend reviewing your original code for possible typos.

[image: Screenshot of me running the code you provided by creating a temp table with the data you gave as an example]